# Reading line by line through text file taking abnormally long time

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, streamreader

I have an issue where I need to read through a text file line by line and place each line into either one string or another if certain criteria is met. The issue I am having is that it is taking a really long time and I'm just wondering is there a quicker way of doing things. I have done a lot of research on how to do this and this is the best I can come up with. Thanks.
(appending to two strings every time due having to output both strings to text files straight after).

The contents are in one huge text file where one piece of information begins at a line starting with "aaa". I have to look through the text file seperating these pieces of information by looking for when lines begin with "aaa".The criteria that separates one piece of information from either fullStr1 or fullStr2 is that character at index 29 is either a blank space(" ") or not. Thanks.

```
        Using reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(file)
            Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine
            Do While (Not line Is Nothing)
                If line.Substring(0, 3) = "aaa" AndAlso line.Substring(29, 1) <> " " Then
                    Do
                        fullStr1 = fullStr1 & line & vbCrLf
                        line = reader.ReadLine
                    Loop While (Not line Is Nothing AndAlso line.Substring(0, 3) <> "aaa")
                ElseIf line.Substring(0, 3) = "aaa" AndAlso line.Substring(29, 1) = " " Then
                    Do
                        fullStr2 = fullStr2 & line & vbCrLf
                        line = reader.ReadLine
                    Loop While (Not line Is Nothing AndAlso line.Substring(0, 3) <> "aaa")
                End If
            Loop
        End Using
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very quick and easy solution is using StringBuilder type instead of String type for variables line and fullStr. (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172824.aspx).
Strings are immutable, which means every time you assign a value to line or fullStr variables, you are not really updating the value of variable that you have in the memory, instead you scrap the previous allocated memory and allocate a new memory space for the variable and assign the new value to the new memory space. This is a lot of overhead and affects the performance of your application.

Comment: Thanks once you mentioned StringBuilder I had it done in minutues, shaved hours off the time.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a long enough text file, it will take a while to scan no matter what you do. But one thing you can do that should help somewhat is use a `StringBuilder`. It's intended for exactly this kind of situation, being tremendously more efficient than concating a huge string together piece by piece.

```
Dim builder1 As New StringBuilder()
Dim builder2 As New StringBuilder()

Using reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(file)
   Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine
   Do While (Not line Is Nothing)
      If line.Substring(0, 3) = "aaa" AndAlso line.Substring(29, 1) <> " " Then
         Do
            builder1.AppendLine(line)
            line = reader.ReadLine
         Loop While (Not line Is Nothing AndAlso line.Substring(0, 3) <> "aaa")
      ElseIf line.Substring(0, 3) = "aaa" AndAlso line.Substring(29, 1) = " " Then
         Do
             builder2.AppendLine(line)
             line = reader.ReadLine
         Loop While (Not line Is Nothing AndAlso line.Substring(0, 3) <> "aaa")
      End If
   Loop
End Using
```

I would also be careful that your loop doesn't get "stuck", since there is no `reader.ReadLine` call in the outer loop. If it gets into a situation where you're in the outer loop and the current line does not start with "aaa", then it will loop forever doing nothing. All you need for this to happen is not have "aaa" on the first line.

Comment: +1. The constant re-allocation and destruction of `string` instances is most likely the culprit here for the slowness.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't the best resolution, but it may be a little quicker. I always put each line in a list. This helps with making the string not so long and then I can go through each by line. But when you are reading in line by line any bigger file will take time since it is reading each line/byte of the file.

```
Private Function ReadInFile(ByVal strFile As String) As List(Of String)
    Dim strLineTemp As String = ""
    Using read As New StreamReader(strFile)
        While read.Peek <> -1
            strLineTemp = read.ReadLine()
            If strLineTemp.Trim <> "" Then
                lstFileData.Add(strLineTemp)
            End If
        End While
    End Using
    Return lstFileData
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? I swapped the condition to use regex and removed the inner loops. Although I would swap the string concatination for 'StringBuilder'I ran out of memory on a big file.

```
Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("aaa.{25} .*")
    st.Start()
    Using reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(file)
        Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine
        Do While (Not line Is Nothing)
            If regex.Match(line).Success = False Then

                fullStr1 = fullStr1 & line & vbCrLf
                line = reader.ReadLine
            Else
                fullStr2 = fullStr2 & line & vbCrLf
                line = reader.ReadLine

            End If

        Loop

    End Using
```